# Why there are two entries for crashkernel parameter in the grub.conf file?

Tags: kernel, linux-kernel, grub, kdump

I'm trying to enable kdump on a server but in the grub configuration file, there are two entries for the crashkernel parameter for each OS entry. I know that this parameter is used to allocate memory to the crash kernel. I'm trying to understand what is the significance of having two entries for the crashkernel parameter in grub.conf.

```
#splashimage=(hd0,0)/grub/splash.xpm.gz
hiddenmenu
title Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server (2.6.32-754.6.3.el6.x86_64)
        root (hd0,0)
        kernel /vmlinuz-2.6.32-754.6.3.el6.x86_64 ro root=/dev/VG01/LV_ROOT      LANG=en_US.UTF-8 SYSFONT=latarcyrheb-sun16 KEYBOARDTYPE=pc KEYTABLE=us crashkernel=auto crashkernel=auto
        initrd /initramfs-2.6.32-754.6.3.el6.x86_64.img
title Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server (2.6.32-696.30.1.el6.x86_64)
        root (hd0,0)
        kernel /vmlinuz-2.6.32-696.30.1.el6.x86_64 ro root=/dev/VG01/LV_ROOT      LANG=en_US.UTF-8 SYSFONT=latarcyrheb-sun16 KEYBOARDTYPE=pc KEYTABLE=us crashkernel=auto crashkernel=auto
        initrd /initramfs-2.6.32-696.30.1.el6.x86_64.img
title Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server (2.6.32-642.13.1.el6.x86_64)
        root (hd0,0)
        kernel /vmlinuz-2.6.32-642.13.1.el6.x86_64 ro root=/dev/VG01/LV_ROOT      LANG=en_US.UTF-8 SYSFONT=latarcyrheb-sun16 KEYBOARDTYPE=pc KEYTABLE=us crashkernel=auto crashkernel=auto
        initrd /initramfs-2.6.32-642.13.1.el6.x86_64.img
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you installed, removed and then re-installed the `kdump` RPM package?

My guess would be that the post-installation script has simply been run twice, for the above-mentioned or some other reason.

Specifying the option twice should have no special meaning, so feel free to delete the extra entries.

Comment: No the kdump package was pre-installed, but it was not configured so i checked the config file and came across this. Actually I checked all the other servers of my organisation, everywhere there are two entries, so I'm not sure what's the reason behind that.